# Editor text resizing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

I am using Ace- Editor like this,

```
<div id="AceEditor"></div>
```

[image]

The blue area is my editor,

```
#AceEditor 
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 300px;
    bottom: 420px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Using Javascript, I've configured the `console log` area to be minimizible as follows,

```
if($("#button").html() == "Minimize")
{
    $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",420);
}
else
{
    $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",0);
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "Minimize"){
        $(this).html("Maximize");
        $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",0);
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("Minimize");
        $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",420);
    }
    $("#ConsoleDisplay, #ConsoleBar").slideToggle();
});
```

Now the problem is, when I press `minimize` the window gets minimized but the text cursor doesn't move below the `420px` lise as shown in the below image,

[image]

So to sovle this,

I've tried changing the CSS AceEditor description to

```
#AceEditor 
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 300px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and now though the text reached the bottom of the page, when the console log is maximized the text doesn't auto adjust to the new `bottom pixel`

How do I solve this problem?

Based on the answer below, I've tried

```
if($("#button").html() == "Minimize")
{
  $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",420).resize();
}
else
{
  $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",0).resize();
}
```

and also tried,

```
if($("#button").html() == "Minimize")
{
  $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",420);
  $('#AceEditor').resize();
}
else
{
  $('#AceEditor').css("bottom",0).resize();
  $('#AceEditor').resize();
}
```

But still the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after changing editor size, you should call `editor.resize()` to let the editor update its size.

Comment: @RahilWazir I'm pretty sure calling [.resize()](http://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.resize) answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue still persists even after making the changes as shown in my above edited question. What to do?

Comment: you are calling resize on `$('#AceEditor')` which is a jquery object. What you need to do is to keep object returned by `ace.edit` like this `var editor = ace.edit('AceEditor');` and later call `editor.resize()`